# Flv Decoder in J2ME for playing Youtube videos

Tags: java-me, youtube, rtsp, mmapi

I am looking for playing flv files using J2ME. Is there any possibility for doing so? Is there any other way to play youtube videos through J2ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `v` parameter from an youTube url, lets call it `VIDEO_ID`.

Open http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/`VIDEO_ID`. The content is in xml format.

Parse the xml to find `media:content` tags.

Open the url attribute of a `media:content` tag with [Manager.createPlayer(url)](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28java.lang.String%29). The protocol is `rtsp`.